# Kotlin coroutines slow start

Tags: performance, kotlin, backend, kotlin-coroutines

I've been attempting to do a bit of performance review on an app I have, it's a back end Kotlin app that just pulls in some data, does a bit of data transformation and dumps it out, nothing too fancy. One thing that caught my eye was the final bit of execution where we dump our final data onto a queue, at first I noticed when we start up the app the final network call takes a very long time at first, sometimes over a second. Normally we run this network call in a coroutine to stop that last call blocking everything but I started trying to time the coroutine and the network call separately and got some odd results, from what I can see the coroutine takes can take forever to launch/complete compared to the network call. It's entirely possible I'm not recording things correctly but this is the general timing approach I have:

```
val coroutineTime - Instant.now().toEpochMillis()
GlobalScope.launch {
executionTime = measureTimeMillis { <--DO Message Sending -->}
totalTime = Instant.now().toEpochMillis() - coroutineTime 
// Log out execution Time and total time 
}
```

Now here what I'll see is something like

```
- totalTime = ~800ms 
- executionTime = ~150ms
```

These aren't one-offs either, I have multiple of these processes going on at once ( up to 10 threads I think) and the first total times will always take significantly longer than the actual executionTime/network call. Eventually after a new dozen messages the overhead will calm down and these times will become equivalent at about 15ms, but having nearly 700ms overhead on coroutine start up seems insane to me.

Is this normal/expected behavior? I've tested this in a separate app and see similar but less extreme results where the first coroutine will take about 70ms to boot up, I'm struggling to find any other examples of this type of discussion outside of kotlin being used in android development.

Answer (score 1):

As a first note, it's almost never a good idea to use the `GlobalScope` unless you really know what you're doing. This is why it was marked as delicate API. You should instead use a scope that is appropriately closed (following the lifecycle of whatever component launches this work).

Now, AFAIK, this `GlobalScope` runs on the default dispatcher, so maybe this is due to a cold start of that default thread pool. Later, it could also be a problem to use this dispatcher for network calls depending on the amount of concurrent coroutines you have. It would be more appropriate to use `Disptachers.IO` instead for IO bound work (or a custom thread pool).

It still doesn't explain the cold start, but I would first change that before investigating.

Comment: I think it actually explains cold starts. OP said there are multiple processes like this invoked at one. If their number is bigger than the number of CPU cores then all threads in the pool will be blocked and some coroutines will have to wait for being dispatched.

Comment: Right, it would explain the cold start if OP is talking about the coroutines started after the `nCores` first coroutines. But the `nCores` first coroutines should start fast, and I thought the OP was saying even the very first ones were slow

Comment: Cheers for the responses guys, I gave it another run just to double check using `Dispatchers.IO` but I still get the same thing, a large disparity between the network call and the coroutine call. Only other thing I can think is there's some reasonably heavy processing before the network call that's going on in potentially 10 other threads (they're JMSListener managed threads, so the thread number scales depending on load) that might be hogging the CPU for so long. I'm going to give it another try with less threads because otherwise Dispatchers.IO doesn't seem to have had a positive effect

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, I have a function that loads some data from shared prefs, makes some calculations on the data (all this done in Dispatcher.Default), and return the result on Dispatcher.Main. I measured how long it took the Coroutine to actually start executing the block inside Dispatchers.Main.launch { } after calculations are done(time from tag2 to tag3 below), and got about 950ms (!!) Here is the function :

```
fun someName() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        //load data and calculations
        Log.d("tag2", "load and calculations took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time))
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate).launch {
            Log.d("tag3", "reached main thread code " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time))
            //do something
            Log.d("tag4", "do something took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time))
        }
    }
}
```

But then I realized this happens while app launch, and main thread is busy creating all the UI, so even with .immediate it takes time until main thread will get to execute the dispatched code... then I tried to run this function after app already started and waiting, and found that from tag2 to tag 3 takes about 1ms (!!) (with .immediate). So looks like when dispatching something on Coroutine, when thread isn't busy it will start immediately

Answer (score -1):

This is expected behavior if you use coroutines inappropriately ;-)

My guess is that your message sending is a blocking operation. By default `GlobalScope.launch()` dispatches coroutines with [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) which is designed to perform CPU-intensive operations, it has a limited number of threads and you should never block when using it. If you do you may run out of threads and coroutines will need to wait until some blocking operations will finish.

If you need to run blocking or IO code, you should use `Dispatchers.IO` instead:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
```

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned, I played around with a few different approaches including using `GlobalScope(Dispatchers.IO)` and `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)` and I'm certain I saw the same thing, I'll give it another run to try and get some actual numbers when I get a chance. For context on your response to Joffrey I'm using a JMSListener which scales up to at most 10 threads, if I'm running on kubes with 2 CPU units I can assume I get 2 cores, is it likely those coroutines will be competing for CPU with the thread creation?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your exact architecture and what does it mean that you have 10 threads. But even if you use just a single thread and with it you invoke your above code 3 times, then first two operations will block in IO and third will wait until they finish. Then you get a large difference between `totalTime` and `executionTime` for a third call.

Comment: Is `GlobalScope` recommended for Android?